# Uncaught ReferenceError: books is not defined

Tags: javascript, object

Write a function `checkBasket()` that lets you know if the item is in the basket or not.

Here is the object basket:

```
amazonBasket = {
 glasses: 1,
 books: 2,
 floss: 100
}
```

What I tried in my JS:

```
function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
   for(item of amazonBasket)
   {
       if(lookingFor===item){
           console.log("This item is in the basket")
       }else{
           console.log("This item is not in the basket")
       }
})
}

 checkBasket(amazonbasket, books)
```

i.e:

checkBasket(amazonbasket,books)

it will return "This item is in the basket"

I don't understand why books are undefined.

Comment: The only `books` shown is as a property of `amazonBasket `. Show more code context related to calling `checkBasket()` as per [mcve]

Comment: Don't just describe your code, provide a complete example demonstrating the problem.  You neither have a variable called `books` nor a variable called `amazonbasket`, so both are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `books` (variable) not `"books"` (string). It's also simpler to use `Object.keys.includes`:

```js
function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  if (Object.keys(basket).includes(lookingFor)) {
    console.log("This item is in the basket");
  } else {
    console.log("This item is not in the basket");
  }
}

amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

checkBasket(amazonBasket, "books");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for in loop to interate each object, then use an if statement to check if the object exist in the basket

```
amazonBasket = {glasses: 1,books: 2,floss: 100}

function CheckBasket(lookingFor, basketToCheck){
  for(items in basketToCheck){
    if(items == lookingFor){
       alert("Item Found");
    }
  }
 }

 CheckBasket( "glasses", amazonBasket);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dictionary to store your products, so the best choice to check if a product is in the basket, would be to iterate over the keys of that dictionary. You can simply use `Object.keys(obj)` to get an array with the keys, then check if the desired product is there.

Keep in mind that you can not use `books` to search against, only if you previously initialized this variable as follows: `let books = "books"`. Otherwise, you should check against the string "books", since an automatic conversion would be made when comparing.

```js
amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  let inBasket = Object.keys(basket);
  let itemFound = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < inBasket.length; ++i) {
    if (lookingFor === inBasket[i]) {
      itemFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  
  if (basket.hasOwnProperty(lookingFor)) {
    console.log("This item is in the basket")
  } else {
    console.log("This item is not in the basket")
  }
}

checkBasket(amazonBasket, "glasses");
checkBasket(amazonBasket, "soda");
```

Of course, this is not the best thing you can do. The dictionaries in java script have the `hasOwnProperty` method that checks if a dictionary has a certain key. Below you have a working example using this.

```js
amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  if (basket.hasOwnProperty(lookingFor)) {
    console.log("This item is in the basket")
  } else {
    console.log("This item is not in the basket")
  }
}

checkBasket(amazonBasket, "glasses");
checkBasket(amazonBasket, "soda");
```

Cheers!